# Why is loss treated as 0 or infinity here?

Tags: expected-value, cross-entropy

I'm reading a beginner's book about deep learning and in the [introduction](http://d2l.ai/chapter_introduction/intro.html), the following cautionary tale is written:

> Now, assume that you built a classifier and trained it to predict if a mushroom is poisonous based on a photograph. Say our poison-detection classifier outputs  $\mathbb{P}(y=deathcap|image)=0.2$. In other words, the classifier is 80% confident that our mushroom is not a death cap. Still, you’d have to be a fool to eat it. That’s because the certain benefit of a delicious dinner isn’t worth a 20% risk of dying from it. In other words, the effect of the uncertain risk by far outweighs the benefit. Let’s look at this in math. Basically, we need to compute the expected risk that we incur, i.e. we need to multiply the probability of the outcome with the benefit (or harm) associated with it:
>
> $$L(action|x)= \mathbb{E}_{y∼p(y|x)}[loss(action,y)]$$
>
> Hence, the loss  $L$  incurred by eating the mushroom is $L(a=eat|x)=0.2\cdot\infty+0.8\cdot0=\infty$, whereas the cost of discarding it is  $L(a=discard|x)=0.2\cdot0+0.8\cdot1=0.8$.

I am confused about why the loss calculations are framed this way. Why is the $loss$ function's range $[0, \infty)$? Could someone explain these expectation calculations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loss is tied in to the problem at hand. In this case, they're saying that if you live you suffer no loss and if you die you suffer infinite loss. You could choose to calculate your loss differently. Perhaps you could figure that you make \$30 per day in interest income so your "loss" if you live is -30, while you calculate that if you die now you'll have lost \$800,000 in lifetime earnings. It's up to you, but no loss and infinite loss seem reasonable for a life-and-death situation from a personal viewpoint. (Given that you will surely die if you eat a poisonous mushroom.)

What may be bothering you is the choice of 0 and infinity, because both of these numbers multiplied times anything return the same value, which render the specific likelihood values unimportant (as long as neither are zero). It doesn't matter if the likelihood of dying is 99% or 0.0001% if the loss is infinite either way.

So what this is saying is that your computer vision algorithm -- given your choice of losses -- will probably never be accurate enough for you to be willing to eat a mushroom that it says is okay.

Comment: Indeed, it seems like the choices were hyperbolic; that seems to be exactly the point, though. I appreciate the answer.